# Polymer - resize not working for an iron-list

Tags: polymer, iron-list

I have a nested element that has a template like this:

```
<template>
  <span>Short text</span>
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[isFullShown]]">[[full]]</template>
</template>
```

This has the `IronResizableBehavior` for which I explicitly call `notifyResize` whenever `isFullShown` changes.

This is nested within another element, that also has the `IronResizableBehavior`

```
<template>
  <nested-element isFullShown="true" full="Full text"></nested-element
</template>
```

which in turn is nested in my iron list

```
<iron-list>
  <template>
    <my-element></my-element>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

When I fire I show the hidden text and call `notifyResize`, if I am looking at the inspection, I'm expecting to see the `translate3D` property change on all the items in the list to indicate that its doing its re-layout due to an item-size-change...but I don't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found an answer?